# c- finding how many times a character occurs in a string

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 40

int main(void)
{
    char buffer1[SIZE] = "computer program";
    char  *ptr;
    int    ch = 'p', j = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i<strlen(buffer1); i++)
    {
        ptr = strchr(buffer1[i], ch);
        if (ptr != 0) j++;
        printf(" %d ", j);
    }
}
```

I want to count how many times a character occurs in a string.
In my program I chose the character 'p'.

I know Pascal, I am learning C now. In pascal is a function called Pos(x,y) which is searching for x in y. Is something familiar to this? I think what I used here is not.

Comment: @mch `ptr=strchr(ptr,ch)` will constantly return the same value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function signature of `strchr` is

```
 char *strchr(const char *s, int c);
```

You need to pass a `char*` but you have passed a `char`. This is wrong.

You have used the `strlen` in loop - making it inefficient. Just calculate the length of the string once and then iterate over it.

```
char *t = buffer;
while(t!= NULL)                                                                                                    
{                                                                                                                       
    t = strchr(t, ch);                                                                                                           
    if( t ) {
        t++;
        occurences++;
    }                                                                                                
}
```

And without using standard library functions you can simply loop over the char array.

```
size_t len = strlen(buffer);
for(size_t i = 0; i < len; i++){
    if( ch == buffer[i]) occurences++;
}
```

Or alternatively without using `strlen`

```
   char *p = buffer;
   while(*p){
      if( *p == ch ){ 
         occurences++;
      }
      p++;
   }
```

Or

```
for(char *p = buffer; *p; occurences += *p++ == ch);
```

Comment: @coderredoc what if I want to find more than just one character?

Comment: @r.r. Then  you will have to ask another question.

Answer (score -2):

Try this example :

```
    int main()
    {
       char buffer1[1000] = "computer program";
       char ch = 'p';
       int i, frequency = 0;


       for(i = 0; buffer1[i] != '\0'; ++i)
       {
           if(ch == buffer1[i])
               ++frequency;
       }

       printf("Frequency of %c = %d", ch, frequency);

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Never use `gets`.

Comment: Please avoid giving code only answers and add some explanation.

Comment: `gets()`? It will not check buffer overflow.